# What's wrong with this XML and QML code? More then one item showns none

Tags: xml, qt, listview, qml

I have a XML structured userlist from my Minecraft server, which I want to show in my QML appliation. It works if there is only one (1) username in the feed, but if there are more, I won't show any at all.

XML structure (let's call it xml.file):

```
<server>
  <status>Online</status>
  <connected-users>
    <user>username1</user>
    <user>username2</user>
  </connected-users>
</server>
```

And then the QML code (shortened):

```
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0
XmlListModel {
    id: msmData
    source: "xml.file"
    query: "/server"

    XmlRole { name: "serverState"; query: "status/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "connectedUser"; query: "connected-users/user/string()" }
}
ListView {
                    id: userList
                    width: parent.width
                    height: units.gu(5)
                    model: msmData
                    delegate: ListItem.Standard {
                        text: connectedUser
                        onClicked: {
                            console.debug('Debug: User clicked "'+connectedUser+'"')
                            checkCurrentUser(connectedUser)
                            PopupUtils.open(userDialog, userList)
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: is the `<user>username2</user><` just a copy/paste typo?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the query for connectedUser to `connected-users/user[1]/string()`, you'll notice you can access username1 again (also note that Xpath starts indexes at 1 rather than 0). [This bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-13688) (though originally reported for Qt 4.7) suggests that support for accessing nested lists is rather lacking.

I hit the same issue attempting to access multiple categories for articles in an RSS feed and got around it by initiating an `XMLHttpRequest`, parsing all my data through JavaScript (including nested lists, whether tags for a blog post or connected users on a server), then appending to a QML `ListModel` attached to a ListView. There may be a way to iterate over nested lists within an XmlListModel – as one of the bug's comments suggests – but I haven't tried the method linked in that comment.

Here's a working example (adapted from a discussion post [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?232839-Qt-Quick-and-DOM-doc-responseXML-returns-null)) using XMLHttpRequest and the XML you provided in a file called 'test.xml':

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1
import Ubuntu.Components.ListItems 0.1 as ListItem

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    ListModel {
        id: msmData
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                var document = request.responseXML.documentElement;
                var msmServer = {
                    status: '',
                    users: []
                };
                for(var i = 0; i < document.childNodes.length; i++) {
                    var record = document.childNodes[i];
                    if (record.tagName === 'status') {
                        msmServer.status = record.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                    } else if (record.tagName === 'connected-users') {
                        for (var k = 0; k < record.childNodes.length; k++){
                            var elem = record.childNodes[k];
                            if(elem.tagName === 'user'){
                                msmServer.users.push({ name: elem.childNodes[0].nodeValue });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                msmData.append(msmServer);
            }
        }
        request.open('GET', 'test.xml');
        request.send();
    }
    ListView {
        id: userList
        width: parent.width
        height: units.gu(5)
        model: msmData
        delegate: ListItem.Subtitled {
            text: status
            subText: {
                var userText = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < users.count; i++) {
                    if (i > 0) userText += ', ';
                    userText += users.get(i).name;
                }
                return userText;
            }
            onClicked: {
                console.debug('Debug: User clicked "'+status+'"')
                for (var i = 0; i < users.count; i++) {
                    console.debug(users.get(i).name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, that is complicated. I'll try that link. It's really irritating. I mean, RSS feed works, so wy not my XML?

Comment: I tried out the link you shared, but it did not want to work. There has to be a way to get this going.

Comment: @DanielHolm I added an example that leverages XMLHttpRequest and QML's limited DOM API. Hope that works.

Comment: samvtran, that did indeed help when clicking on the status, but I dont know how to show the usernames in a listitem?

Comment: @DanielHolm I updated the code sample, changing the ListItem to "Subtitled" and giving an example of iterating over the usernames to provide a simple list of usernames as the subtext.

Comment: Thank you again, @samvtran . The thing that I'm now trying to figure out, is how to do a ListItem for each connected user, and also download the xml file locally so that it can be read. I need to be able to click on each user separately and pass it trough a function that I already got working.